# Waterfall style functions get wrong arguments passed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reverse engineer async's waterfall function to better understand how it works.
While I've come up with the following code which works mostly, it has one strange behavior I cannot explain: Arguments passed to the next function seem to get lost somewhere, being replaced by the load event in browsers and the require function in node.

My code:

```
const waterfall = (callbacks, callback) => {
  callback = callback || function() {
    };

  let counter      = 0,
      errors       = [],
      results      = [],
      nextExecutor = (err, res) => {
        let argsArray           = Array.from(arguments),
            error               = (argsArray.length >= 2 && !!argsArray[ 0 ]
                ? argsArray[ 0 ]
                : false
            ),
            result              = (error
                ? argsArray[ 1 ]
                : argsArray[ 0 ]
            ),
            currentIteration    = counter++,
            currentNextExecutor = (counter === callbacks.length
                ? () => {
              }
                : nextExecutor
            );

        if (error !== false) {
          errors.push(error);
        }

        results.push(result);

        callbacks[ currentIteration ].call(
          {},
          currentNextExecutor,
          result
        );

        if (counter === callbacks.length) {
          callback.call(
            {},
            (errors.length > 0
                ? errors[ 0 ]
                : null
            ),
            results
          );
        }
      };

  callbacks[ counter++ ](nextExecutor);
};

waterfall([
  function(next) {
    console.log('hi! this is first.');
    setTimeout(() => {
      next(null, 10);
    }, 200);
  },
  function(next, x) {
    console.log('hi! this is second: ' + x);
    setTimeout(() => {
      next(null, x);
    }, 200);
  },
  function(next, x) {
    console.log('hi! this is third: ' + x);
    x++;
    setTimeout(() => {
      next(null, x);
    }, 200);
  },
  function(next, x) {
    console.log('hi! this is last.');
    setTimeout(() => {
      next(null, x);
    }, 200);
  }
], (error, results) => {
  console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  console.log('Results: ' + JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

Expected output:

```
hi! this is first.
hi! this is second: 10
hi! this is third: 10
hi! this is last.
Error: null
Results: [ 10, 10, 11, 11]
```

Actual output:

```
hi! this is first.
hi! this is second: function require(path) { ... }
hi! this is third: function require(path) { ... }
hi! this is last.
Error: {}
Results: [null,null,null]
```

I don't understand where things go wrong - the `arguments` object has no reference of the passed value.

*Notice: This is not intended to mimic async source code, because I haven't looked at it yet. I wanted to solve the problem by myself for learning purposes.*

Comment: If you downvote a question it would be nice to let the questioning know what you critize about it so they can improve.

Comment: Your `result` is one of parameters passed to function. Check this.

Comment: @Justinas yep that's intentionally so, since I wanted to be able to pass values between the individual callbacks (you can see this in the example at the bottom of the code, where I pass x around and increment it)...

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

*Since arrow functions don't bind their own `arguments` variable, I was using the parent scope `arguments`. Which, incidentially, was the `load` event in browsers or `require` in node.*

#### Original Answer:

Solved the problem - interestingly enough, using arrow functions does not work as intended, though I don't know why. Swapping the declaration for `nextExecutor` to a standard function (and refactoring the argument handling a bit) seems to fix the issue.

Thus, the `nextExecutor` code looks like this:

```
nextExecutor = function(error, result) {
    let currentIteration    = counter++,
        currentNextExecutor = (counter === callbacks.length
            ? function() {}
            : nextExecutor
        );

    if (!!error) {
      errors.push(error);
    }

    results.push(result);

    callbacks[ currentIteration ].call(
      {},
      currentNextExecutor,
      result
    );

    if (counter === callbacks.length) {
      callback.call(
        {},
        (errors.length > 0
            ? errors[ 0 ]
            : null
        ),
        results
      );
    }
  };

  callbacks[ counter++ ](nextExecutor);
};
```

Comment: `arguments` does not work with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), as some more things ...

Comment: @NinaScholz I tried the `...args` with spread operator first that didn't seem to work either - that's an interesting point I haven't heard yet, I always thought the major difference was the handling of `this`. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well your problem was here

```
result = (error
  ? argsArray[ 1 ]
  : argsArray[ 0 ]
),
```

Since error is always false, result would be args[0] which is always null ?

argsArray[indexes] are inverted in other words ...